# strftime in __del__ causes importlib error

Tags: python, python-datetime

When testing the following python code snippet I get errors both with python2.7 and python3.4:

```
from datetime import datetime

class Test(object):
    def __del__(self):
        print(datetime.now().strftime('%Y'))

a = Test()
```

**Error with python2.7:**

```
Exception RuntimeError: 'sys.meta_path must be a list of import hooks' in <bound method Test.__del__ of <__main__.Test object at 0x7f151163b290> ignored
```

**Error with python3.4:**

```
Exception ignored in: <bound method Test.__del__ of <__main__.Test object at 0x7f9a140e1160>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in __del__
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2222, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2155, in _find_spec
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Does any one have any idea of what's going on here?
Removing strftime or replacing it with isoformat() seems to work well, this is really weird.

Comment: Yeah, that's one of the reasons `__del__` methods are a bad idea. They can get called during interpreter shutdown, while the Python interpreter is busy self-destructing. It's like trying to make your bed while your house is being demolished.

Comment: Indeed, if you explicitly delete the object or generate it inside a function, works as expected.

Comment: If the error is only caused at interpreter shutdown, you should mention this in the question.  That behaviour is expected.  If you're seeing it outside of shutdown context, that behaviour is not expected - add more details to show how to reproduce it.

Comment: It does happen at interpreter shutdown in the \_\_del\_\_ method of my main object.
The goal here was originally to write some lo file (including a date) before exiting interpreter.

Comment: @Morian what you are really looking for is an atexit function to register. That happens before objects/modules start getting destroyed.